# getting custom legend on canvas on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have drawn multiple-line plot on a single canvas, using different line styles. But not sure how to get the `legend` done.
The line I'm using to plot is like:

```
ax.plot(x_ra,y_ra,'g^-', x_rb,y_rb,'b-', x_rc,y_rc,'y^--', x_rd,y_rd,'^-', x_re,y_re,'b^-.', x_rf,y_rf,'--')
```

Now I can utilize some idea on how can I get a legend box like:
`g^-`  - A
`b-`   - B
`y^--` - D etc.
 Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the labels during the call to `legend`, if you also name the `Line2D` objects that `plot` returns.

Here's a simple MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_ra,y_ra = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(0,10,1)
x_rb,y_rb = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(1,11,1)
x_rc,y_rc = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(2,12,1)
x_rd,y_rd = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(3,13,1)
x_re,y_re = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(4,14,1)
x_rf,y_rf = np.arange(0,10,1),np.arange(5,15,1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
mylines = ax.plot(
            x_ra,y_ra,'g^-', 
            x_rb,y_rb,'b-', 
            x_rc,y_rc,'y^--', 
            x_rd,y_rd,'^-', 
            x_re,y_re,'b^-.', 
            x_rf,y_rf,'--'
            )

ax.legend(mylines,['A','B','C','D','E','F'],loc=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]